How to merge down rows in a single data frame
I'm trying to condense a table in which rows show the flavor of ice cream fed to each individual per day with number of scoops each day. The table has multiple repeat rows and staggered rows, which I would like to condense into one where all the staggered rows become one neat row. The number of scoops would need to be summed by flavor. The challenge is that the table is quite large (100 x 1000), with a non-uniform number of rows for each individual. There are dozens of other columns not shown in the examples below, which contain identifiers that are thankfully not staggered.
Before example:

After:

I have tried this solution but am trying to apply it across the dozens of other rows that were not staggered in the dataset (without individually extracting each column and then cbinding).
I also tried opening the file in excel and running the Consolidate feature with SUM function, which gives the "Source overlaps destination areas" error. I plan to run it with Macros once I can it out.

library(tidyverse); df |> pivot_longer(-c(ID, 'number of scoops')) |> count(ID, value, wt = 'number of scoops')?

1) Using the data in the Note at the end, coalesce the day columns to generate temporary grouping column g and then fill in the day columns with it using across.  Finally sum scoops by those columns.  Depending on what is wanted .by = -scoops may be used in place of the .by= shown.
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

DF %>%
  mutate(g = pmap(pick(starts_with("day")), coalesce), 
         across(starts_with("day"), ~ g)) %>%
  reframe(scoops = sum(scoops), .by = c(ID, starts_with("day")))

##   ID day1 day2 scoops
## 1  1    a    a     10
## 2  1    b    b     26

Optionally eliminate dependence on purrr by using this to calculate g
coalesce(!!!.[grep("day", names(.))])

1a) This variation works but currently requires the github version of tidyr as fill in the CRAN version does not yet support .by= .
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
# devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  mutate(g = pmap(pick(starts_with("day")), coalesce)) %>%
  fill(starts_with("day"), .direction = "updown", .by = g) %>%
  reframe(scoops = sum(scoops), .by = c(ID, starts_with("day")))

2) This is a base R version.  Get a logical selection vector of the day columns, days. Then use apply to compute a grouping vector and replace each day column with it.  Finally sum scoops by the remaining columns.
days <- startsWith(names(DF), "day")
replace(DF, days, apply(DF[days], 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)) |>
  aggregate(scoops ~ ., data = _, sum)

##   ID day1 day2 scoops
## 1  1    a    a     10
## 2  1    b    b     26

Note
Next time please post the data in text form using dput or otherwise so that others can easily use it. In the absence of that we have provided the following data frame this time.
DF <- data.frame(ID = 1, 
   day1 = rep(c("a", NA, "b", NA), each = 2), 
   day2 = rep(c(NA, "a", NA, "b"), each = 2),
   scoops = 1:8
)

